# How to keep domain in iframe when not having .html source?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

If we have an iframe with a defined page the domain gets inherited by the iframe, and then you have access to modify the iframe content from the parent frame without any cross origin / domain problems. But what happens you don't have a defined page in your iframe source ?!

```
 <iframe id='myFrame' />

 var src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(
          "<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><h1>Title</h1></body></html>");

 $('#myFrame').attr('src', src);
```

At this point if I try to use something like:

```
 $('#myFrame').contents().find('html').html('new template');
```

... I get **domain** error messages.

Is there any way to pass the parent domain to the iframe ?

I don't want to use **postMessage / receiveMessage** communication.

Comment: not sure that what you are trying to do. But see this fiddle if this can help you. http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set iframe's src to a data url ,chrome (and maybe others) will start treating it as cross origin.

The trick is to *not* set the src.

```
 var source =  "<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><h1>Title</h1></body></html>";

 $('#myFrame').contents().find('html').html(source);
 $('#myFrame').contents().find('html').html('<body>Hi2</body>');
```